# How to unset offset in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, offset

I am having an issue unsetting the offset of an element. Here is my code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hhQH2/39/

And here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div class="div" id="378246"></div>
<div class="promoBook" id="378246"></div>
<div class="availability"><div class="avClose">X</div></div>
<div class='tellme'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.promoBook{
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 100px;
background: #333;
width: 120px;
height: 45px;
    color: #fff;
}
.availability{
position: absolute;
background: red;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
//pop up availability 
$(".promoBook").click(function(){
    var btnavail = $(".availability");
    var bookId = $(this).attr("id");
    var btnpos = $(this).offset();

    $(".tellme").text(btnpos.left + btnpos.top);

    //change position of availability div
    btnavail.offset(btnpos);
    btnavail.show();
    $(".avClose").click(function(){
    btnavail.hide();
    btnavail.offset({left:0,top:0});    
    });

    });​
```

The main problem is that it is not erasing the set offset... it holds the old one and adds the new. I hope this makes sense.. any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jQuery doc :

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.

I believe it is the same when you want to set it ;)

To resolve your problem, just reverse the two lines of close method :

```
$(".avClose").click(function(){
    btnavail.offset({left:0,top:0});    
    btnavail.hide();

});
```